# Modify DataFrame values against a particular value in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

See my code:

```scala
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("ReadFiles").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val data: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", "true")
  .option("inferschema", "true")
  .csv("Resources/atom.csv")

data.show()
```

Data looks like:

```
ID  Name  City  newCol1  newCol2
1   Ali   lhr   null     null
2   Ahad  swl    1        10
3   Sana  khi   null     null
4   ABC   xyz   null     null
```

New list of values:

```
val nums: List[Int] = List(10,20)
```

I want to add these values where `ID=4`. So that DataFrame may look like:

```
ID  Name  City  newCol1  newCol2
1   Ali   lhr   null     null
2   Ahad  swl    1        10
3   Sana  khi   null     null
4   ABC   xyz    10       20
```

I wonder if it is possible. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, Use **`when otherwise`** statements for this case.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    
df.withColumn("newCol1", when(col("id") === 4, lit(nums(0))).otherwise(col("newCol1")))
  .withColumn("newCol2", when(col("id") === 4, lit(nums(1))).otherwise(col("newCol2")))
  .show()

//+---+----+----+-------+-------+
//| ID|Name|City|newCol1|newCol2|
//+---+----+----+-------+-------+
//|  1| Ali| lhr|   null|   null|
//|  2|Ahad| swl|      1|     10|
//|  3|Sana| khi|   null|   null|
//|  4| ABC| xyz|     10|     20|
//+---+----+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Does it involve any imports?

Comment: @AyezaMalik, import functions should be fine enough... `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`